# WordPress shortcodes for terms

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I was trying to create shortcode for custom taxonomy terms dynamically. But failing to do so.
Suppose, if there is a term called "wordpress" then I should be able to query all the posts associated with that term via shortcode. 
To be more precise, suppose if there is a taxonomy called 'event' and under that taxonomy there are multiple terms. So, I was trying to query posts under each of the term via shortcode of each of the term.

Here is what I tried:

```
function wordpress_recent_post( $atts, $content ) {
  $a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'cat' => '',
  ), $atts );
  $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'offset' => 0,
    'category_name' => $a['cat'],
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
  );
  $recent_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
  ob_start();
  if ( ! $recent_posts-> have_posts() ) {
    return 'No Posts Found for ' . $a['cat'];
  }
  while ( $recent_posts->have_posts() ) {
    $recent_posts->the_post();
    the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' );
    if ( '' != $a['cat'] ) {
      $href = '/category/' . $a['cat'];
    } else {
      $href = '/blog';
    }
    echo "<p><a href='$href'>Read More" . ucwords( $a['cat'] ) . '</a></p>';
  }
  wp_reset_query();
  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'wordpress_recent_post', array($this, 'wordpress_recent_post') );
```

And then I used this to call the posts from a term called "features" whose id is '183' (suppose)
[wordpress_recent_post cat="183"]

Any help would be really very appreciable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding term slug did it. There should be slug not id, like this:
[wordpress_recent_post cat="features"]